# Refresh EditText value from Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to get specific date selected from a user and then show it in an EditText. I am using the following method in which after selection of Date from DatePickerDialog in  onDateSet() i am updating the EditText but Edit Text never updates (Dont show the selected value ) pls. guide whats wrong with the code?

```
public class CreateReport extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText blockName;
    EditText eventDesc;
    public EditText eventDate;
    public EditText eventTime;
    EditText reporterName;
    EditText reporterCnic;
    public static Calendar userCalendar;
    private String Lat, Long;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_report);
//        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
//        ab.setTitle("Create Reoprt");
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        blockName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.block_name);
        eventDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Date);
        eventTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Time);
        reporterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reporter_name);
        reporterName.setText(AppSettings.getUserName());
        reporterCnic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reporter_cnic);
        reporterCnic.setText(AppSettings.getUserCnic());
        reporterName.setEnabled(false);
        reporterCnic.setEnabled(false);
        eventDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.event_desc);
        eventDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });
        eventTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTimePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });
        if (bundle != null) {
            Lat = bundle.getString("lat");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Latitude" + Lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Long = bundle.getString("Long");
        }
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.setOnTimeSelectedListener(new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                String myFormat = "HH:mm";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(hourOfDay, minute);

                String formattedTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                eventTime.setText(formattedTime);
                Toast.makeText(CreateReport.this, "Time" + formattedTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.setOnDateSelectedListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                // Do something with the date chosen by the user
                String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);

                String formattedTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                eventDate.setText(formattedTime);
                Toast.makeText(CreateReport.this, "Date" + formattedTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }













    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mListener;

        public TimePickerFragment() {
            // Default constructor. Required
        }

        public void setOnTimeSelectedListener(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getContext(),mListener, hour, minute, true);
        }
    }


    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mListener;

        public DatePickerFragment() {
            // Default constructor. Required
        }

        public void setOnDateSelectedListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), mListener, year, month, day);
        }
    }
}
```

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/crt_event_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/block_name"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
                android:hint="Block Name"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ev_Date"
                android:inputType="datetime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
                android:hint="Event Date"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ev_Time"
                android:inputType="datetime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
                android:hint="Event Time"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reporter_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
                android:hint="Reporting Official"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reporter_cnic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
                android:hint="Reporting Official"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/event_desc"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/loginfields_borders"
                android:hint="Event Description"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Logs Generated after clicking Date Edittext and due to which destroy of CreateReport Activity

```
      04-19 21:30:16.281 28941-28941/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
        Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
        04-19 21:30:16.517 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.aiousecurityapplication-1/lib/arm64
        04-19 21:30:16.534 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
        04-19 21:30:16.563 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
        04-19 21:30:16.614 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
        04-19 21:30:16.901 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication W/PhoneWindow: Previously focused view reported id 2131296398 during save, but can't be found during restore.
        04-19 21:30:16.907 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
        04-19 21:30:16.911 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
        04-19 21:30:16.988 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.net.HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl
        04-19 21:30:17.022 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
        04-19 21:30:17.022 28941-28964/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
        04-19 21:30:17.033 28941-28964/com.example.aiousecurityapplication W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
        04-19 21:30:17.111 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in 
        android.widget.ListView
        04-19 21:30:17.208 28941-28941/com.example.aiousecurityapplication E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
        04-19 21:30:18.734 28941-28946/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=29KB
        04-19 21:30:18.735 28941-28946/com.example.aiousecurityapplication I/art: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=29KB
        Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below.

The idea is to implement the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` and to pass it to the DialogFragment.
Don't store the time in a static field as you have access to this information directly in the Dialog method called when the user selects a date (`public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)`).

As the listener is implemented in the Activity, you have access to the `EventDate` field.

Btw, I've renamed it `mEventDate` as the fields/variables should not be named with a capital as first letter. Naming the fields with a 'm' as starting letter is best practice as it differentiate the class variables from local variable.

An other improvement should be to put the `DatePickerFragment` in a separated class file as it's confusing. Everyone (including myself) thought you could have access to the `EventDate` field directly as we haven't noticed the static class when reading the code quicly.

**EDITED**

```
public class CreateReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText mEventDate;
    private String Lat, Long;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_report);

        mEventDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Date);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(Context context, View v) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.setOnDateSelectedListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                // Do something with the date chosen by the user
                String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);

                String formattedTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                mEventDate.setText(formattedTime);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Date" + formattedTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mListener;

        public DatePickerFragment() {
            // Default constructor. Required
        }

        public void setOnDateSelectedListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), mListener, year, month, day);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I have tried this code and when i start CreateReport Activity. it crashes and returns to calling Activity. And it happens so quickly that Logs gets washed away? pls. guide

Comment: I've updated it. Try again with the new one. If it crashes, please post the logs as otherwise I can't help

Comment: I've tested the above code, works perfectly fine. Are you sure you've copied it correctly?

Comment: I have copied updated code still same issue persists.

Comment: Where is your `showDatePickerDialog` method called?

Comment: Your probably have another issue not related to the question. Can you please post the logs?

Comment: It is called in EditText android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"

Comment: Please add your layout to the question. AND the logs

Comment: I'd guess the error is from your layout. Was your app working (except the dialog) before you asked the question?

Comment: The logs created right after start and subsequent destroy of CreateReport get Vanished... Still i will add Logs generated after wards. and XML code as in question

Comment: Every thing else in app is still working so as the CreateReport untill i click EditTextBox

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. Change your method for `public void showDatePickerDialog(View v)` (basically remove Context) and in the Toast do: `Toast.makeText(CreateReport.this, "Date" + formattedTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: When you call a method on `onClick` from a View (your `EditText` in your case) the only parameter MUST be the View, otherwise the system doesn't find the method. So basically your app crashes because you try to call a method which doesn't exists

Comment: That's why it's preferable to set the onClick listener not in the XML but in the Java code (`myView.setOnClickListener(...)`) as it's more readable, maintainable and any errors are managed by the compiler, not at runtime (unlike the xml)

Comment: Awesome Man That was the fault i have corrected it and it works fine. I have spent  hours on this

Comment: Cool! But what is your IDE (and its version) as Android Studio (at least in version 3.0.1) shows an error in the xml, telling you the method doesn't exist?

Comment: I am Using Android Studio 3.1 But in my case it didnt

Comment: Pls. have a look i have updated the code in my question for TimePickerDialog but it is giving error for TimePicker and DatePicker is working fine

Comment: If i change hours only on the dialog and press ok It will work fine ... But if i change minutes or dont change anything and press ok it will crash

Comment: `cal.set(hourOfDay, minute);` is not the way to set the time to a calendar. Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)). I think it'd have been better to ask a new question, and in any case to provide the error log as it's difficult for us to find your issue otherwise. If you are not able to get the log (as you said they disappear quickly) maybe you should have a look at your AS settings as something is maybe not correctly set

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented by many ways. I recommend first one, where you can customize  `OnDateSelected` interface according to your need. and call the date picker from any class.

```
public class CreateReport extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText EventDate;
    public static Calendar usercalendar;
    private String Lat, Long;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_report);

        EventDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Date);


    }
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(new DatePickerFragment.OnDateSelected() {
            @Override
            public void onSelected(String date) {
                EventDate.setText(date);
            }
        });
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        Context context;

        OnDateSelected onDateSelected;

        public DatePickerFragment(OnDateSelected onDateSelected) {
            this.onDateSelected = onDateSelected;
        }

        interface OnDateSelected{
            void onSelected(String date);
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            usercalendar.set(year, month, day);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            View dialogName = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_create_report, null);
            ((EditText) dialogName.findViewById(R.id.ev_Date)).setText(sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()));
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Date" + sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (onDateSelected!=null) onDateSelected.onSelected(sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime())); 
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class CreateReport extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText EventDate;
    public static Calendar usercalendar;
    private String Lat, Long;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_report);

        EventDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_Date);


    }
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(EventDate);
        newFragment.setEditText(EventDate);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        Context context;
        private EditText editText;

        public void setEditText(EditText editText) {
            this.editText = editText;
        }

        interface OnDateSelected{
            void onSelected(String date);
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            usercalendar.set(year, month, day);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            View dialogName = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_create_report, null);
            ((EditText) dialogName.findViewById(R.id.ev_Date)).setText(sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()));
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Date" + sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (editText !=null) editText .setText(sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First Method gives this error "Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]"

Comment: Yes I seen that, I am not on computer right now, can you set interface same as edittext not in constructor

Comment: If you set interface by an method it will sure work, or I will update my post after some time

Comment: I am sorry didnt get what you are saying.... can you explain why below line of code is not working ? 
        ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ev_Date)).setText(sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()));

Comment: Or the one in my question ?

Comment: That will not work, use interface for same, as I posted, just set interface by method. Like I did for edittext

Answer (score 0):

Normally use EventDate.setText(sdf.format(usercalendar.getTime()));

it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getDatePickerPOP() {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(ViewersList.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

            Calendar calander2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calander2.setTimeInMillis(0);
            calander2.set(selectedyear, selectedmonth, selectedday, 0, 0, 0);
            java.util.Date SelectedDate = (java.util.Date) calander2.getTime();
            DateFormat dateformat_US = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
            String StringDateformat_US = dateformat_US.format(SelectedDate);
            EventTextView.setText(StringDateformat_US);
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000);
    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
    mDatePicker.show();
}
```

Comment: EventDate is not accessible in this method even it being public.. ANy other method ?